# Iterate through array within React Component render's function

Tags: reactjs, arrays, antd

I have an array that I've confirmed has content, and the keys are correct.

I'm trying to iterate through that array and put an image via the `item.url` key into an Antd Card element.  Below is the code I have.  It compiles fine, but there is no output.

What needs to change to iterate over the array AND display the results of the Card elements thats being created?

```
        return(<div>{this.imageDetails.forEach((item) => {
                    <Card hoverable cover={<img src={item.url}/>}>
                        <Meta title="Unoptimized Image" description="Need to optimize"/>
                    </Card>})}
              </div>)
    }
```

Comment: use map instead of foreach

Comment: I should have mentioned I had tried that as well, unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: you also need to return inside the map `return (<Card.....</Card>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use map function to return component like so

```
return(
  <div>
      {this.imageDetails.map(item => (
          <Card hoverable cover={<img src={item.url}/>}>
              <Meta title="Unoptimized Image" description="Need to optimize"/>
          </Card>)}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Looked like my issue was twofold, need map AND use parentheses instead of brackets for the callback function. Follow up question, I'm pretty new to coding in general, why did the use of parentheses vs brackets matter?  There was no compile error.

Comment: Parentheses `()` are used for function calls while braces `{}` are used to group statements or declarations.

Comment: Considering this is JSX and not straight JS that makes complete sense.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `forEach` and `map` is that `forEach` is used to iterate through an array and returns `undefined`, while `map` can also iterate through an array, but it returns a new array (of JSX elements in this case). With `map`, you can create dynamic length lists in React. Additionally, curly braces are used to denote code blocks, while parentheses (in React) are used to create JSX elements.